# Clipping Border doesn't work sometimes

Tags: import

I'm pretty new to Blender and I have created an environment. I import a vehicle model using the apend option but I have problems when trying to display only a portion of the car model. I press Alt+B and select the zone I want to cut, but for some reason Blender does weird things like making all objects disappear or cutting other zones. When I use the same tool in the project where i take the vehicle model from I don't have any trouble. What could be the origin of such issues?

Edit:

So this is my environment with the car model imported

I press CTRL + 1 to have the next view.

And I select an area with ALT + B. The result is this:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, everything disappears and I can't see the portion selected. There is another annoying thing. The vehicle surface is smooth in the original file, but when imported it is not like that anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: It's maybe linked to the parameter of viewport (i think to perspective vs orthot view). A screenshot of the problem would be usefull.

Comment: can you add a screenshot in your question?

Comment: Screenshots added. If you need more info just let me know. I haven't figured out how to solve this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem in clipping settings:

[image]

The end point is extremely big! Set end point less than one thousand.

Comment: Indeed the clipping distance beween start and end should be set so that it takes encompasses the whole scene but not much else. It makes no sense to set the end clip to the distance to the next galaxy. There is a limit to the precision of the 3D representation, having such a range between start and end can generate issues with z-fighting